# Show data from ICollection ViewModel

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc, repository-pattern, entity-framework-core

I need a little help. I have 4 entities.

Entity 1 has FK from Entity 2 and 3. But Entity 4 has FK from Entity 1.

Entity4 has properties:

ID as primary key

FK_Entity1

code as string

Now if my ViewModel has next code:

```
class ViewModel.cs
{
public    int id {get;set;}
public string name {get;set;}
public virtual Entity2 Entity2 {get;set;}
public virtual Entity3 Entit3 {get;set;}
public virtual ICollection<Entity4> Entity4 {get;set;}
}
```

in controller with next code I'm getting info:

```
public class NameController : Controller
{
    private IRepository<Entity1> _repoEntity1;

    public Entity1Controller(IRepository<Entity1> repoEntity1)
    {
        _repoEntity1 = repoEntity1;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        string[] entities = { "Entity2", "Entity3" };
        var items = _repoEntity1.GetAll(entities);
        return View(Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ViewModel>>(items));
    }

}
```

In view I want to show every code from Entity4 for exist FK_Entity1

Example:

If Entity1 has record as Id =1, name= "John", FK_Entity2 = 1, FK_Entity3 = 3

and Entity4 has records Id = 1, FK_Entity = 1, code = "test"

id = 2, FK_Entity = 1, code = "ABCD"

I want to see code(ABCD and test)

In View I put like this

```
model IEnumerable<ViewModel>
foreach(var item in Model)
{
   item.name
   item.Entity2.name
   item.Entity3.name
}
```

But cant put @item.Entity4.code, how should I do that ?

UPDATE:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetAll(string[] includes
    {           
        return includes.Aggregate(entities.AsQueryable(), (query, path) => 
        query.Include(path));
    }
```

Here is code from repository, I think I should modify this in order to join Entity4 ?

Answer (score 0):

In your ViewModel **Entity4** use as an ICollection. You can't access generic list property without looping. That's why you can put only item.Entity4 inside your foreach loop.

Comment: Ok, agree on that. But if I put break point when I run GetAll(), Entity4 is null, so to get data for Entity4 as I understand I need to modify GetAll function in order to join Entity4. Correct me if I'm wrong ?

Comment: Yes it should be null, definitely you should include Entity4 as well. when you   include only Entity4 you can see both entity2 & 3

Answer (score 0):

Here is code how I solve my problem

```
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            string[] entities = { "Entity2", "Entity3" };
            var items = _repoEntity1.GetAll(entities);
            var itemsEntity4 = _repoEntity4.Getall("Entity1");
            foreach(var item in items)
            {
                foreach(var x in itemsEntity4)
                {
                      if(item.id == x.Entity1.Id)
                      {
                         item.Entity4.Add(x);
                      }
                }
            }
            return View(Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ViewModel>>(items));
        }
```